# How do I test Expo application without building apk with appium?

Tags: react-native, expo, appium

I try to make some tests on my Expo application but I can't launch it with appium,

Here is my `capabilities`:

```
const capabilities = {
  platformName: 'android',
  deviceName: 'Emulator1',
  automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
  pkg: 'host.exp.exponent',
  intentAction: 'android.intent.action.VIEW',
  activity: 'host.exp.exponent.experience.HomeActivity',
  appWaitForLaunch: true,
  path: '/wd/',
  port: 4723,
};
```

I got this :

```
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
[0-0] 2021-02-18T12:34:11.688Z ERROR webdriver: unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
    at Object.getErrorFromResponseBody (/Users/kanka/Desktop/projects/expo-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:189:12)
    at WebDriverRequest._request (/Users/kanka/Desktop/projects/expo-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/request.js:168:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[0-0] 2021-02-18T12:34:11.690Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: Failed to create session.
The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
    at Object.startWebDriverSession (/Users/kanka/Desktop/projects/expo-tests/node_modules/webdriver/build/utils.js:68:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
2021-02-18T12:34:11.810Z DEBUG @wdio/local-runner: Runner 0-0 finished with exit code 1
[0-0] FAILED in undefined - /tests/App.test.js
2021-02-18T12:34:11.811Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook

Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:01
```

Comment: there is not path and port in capabilities options tab, it goes to another tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `"webdriverio": "^7.0.7"` package: try updating your configuration file like this :

### wdio.conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    services: ['appium'],
    port: 4723,
    path: '/wd/hub/',
    hostname: 'localhost',
    protocol: 'http',
    specs: [
        './test/specs/**/*.js',
    ],
    maxInstances: 1,
    capabilities: [{
        platformName: 'android',
        deviceName: 'test', // Change to the name of the AVD you're using
        automationName: 'UiAutomator2',
        appPackage: 'host.exp.exponent',
        appActivity: 'host.exp.exponent.experience.HomeActivity',
        appWaitActivity: 'host.exp.exponent.experience.HomeActivity',
        intentAction: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
        appWaitForLaunch: true,
        newCommandTimeout: 180,
        uiautomator2ServerInstallTimeout: 100000,
        adbExecTimeout: 1000000,
        skipLogcatCapture: true,
    }],

    logLevel: 'trace',
    bail: 0,
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 1200000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['spec'],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 180000,
    },
};
```

**`path` `port` are not in `capabilities` array.**

Comment: Thanks ! I already manage to fix my config, now I cannot test my app in expo application ... someone told me to use deeplink but I don't understand how it works